# jQM:How to set initial state of select populated from Sqlite

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I made a script that contains 2 linked select controls: first one is populated by SQLite data that present all car manufacturers, second select control shall be populated with car  models based on state of first select control. I know how to write code to read and populate select controls but I can't to set up initial state of first select to 0 and in same time set up initial state of second select. I tried many tricks but even select controls were correct populated always shows empty! I tried:

```
<select id="sel_manufacturer" onchange="checkMe(); return false;">
</select>

<select id="sel_model">
</select>

 //code (part):       
$('#sel_manufacturer').selectmenu();
$(document).on('pageinit', "#pocetna", function() {
    fillManufacturers(); //open, read Sqlite and populate first select control
});
...
//at end of  the function is code:
var select = document.getElementById("sel_manufacturer");
if (typeof(select.onchange) == "function") select.onchange();
...
function checkMe {
    document.getElementById('sel_manufacturer').selectedIndex=1;
    $('#sel_manufacturer').selectmenu('refresh', true);
}
```

But checking in GC console during test mentioned select doesn't appears with any selected option! I tried to change 'pageinit' to 'pageshows' but no score. But code of checkMe() function is working when there is select control with hard coded options, directly in script!? Is it possible to achieve? Script is based on jQ 11.1.1 & jQM 1.4.5. Thank you.

Comment: did you set the `selected` attribute, for one `option` ?

Comment: No, I didn't.. just I have read Dbtable and populated Select controls but after that no first option but empty shows until click/touch when is possible see that options are "bellow surface"... I tried everything but it seems that page isn't aware of select when code is fired because doesn't show .size() nor index(0). Strange. It should be peace of cake in comparison with accordion but... isn't! :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just a matter of asynchronous response from your database, anyway, below you will find an example with chained asynchronous calls from a  ajax placeholders. You may replace *users* with "manufacturers* and *todos* with *models* but the principle is the same.

```js
function getToDo(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?id=" + id,
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $.mobile.loading("show");
    },
    success: function(todos) {
      $("#todo-id span").text(todos[0].id);
      $("#todo-title span").text(todos[0].title);
      $("#todo-status span").text(todos[0].completed ? "Closed" : "Open");
    },
    complete: function() {
      $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }
  });
}

function getToDos(userId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=" + userId,
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $.mobile.loading("show");
    },
    success: function(todos) {
      var options = "";
      $.each(todos, function(index, todo) {
        options += '<option value="' + todo.id + '">' + todo.title + '</option>';
      });
      $("#select-todos")
        .html("")
        .append(options)
        .selectmenu("refresh", true);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }
  }).then(function() {
    $("#select-todos").trigger("change");
  });
}

function getUsers() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      method: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $.mobile.loading("show");
      },
      success: function(users) {
        var options = "";
        $.each(users, function(index, user) {
          options += '<option value="' + user.id + '">' + user.name + '</option>';
        });
        $("#select-users")
          .append(options)
          .selectmenu("refresh", true);
      },
      complete: function() {
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
      }
    })
    .then(function() {
      $("#select-users").trigger("change");
    });
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#choice-select", function(e, ui) {
  $("#select-users").change(function() {
    getToDos($(this).val());
  });
  $("#select-todos").change(function() {
    getToDo($(this).val());
  });
  getUsers();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="choice-select">
    <div data-role="content" role="main">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-users">Users:</label>
        <select name="select-users" id="select-users" data-native-menu="false">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-todos">To-Do's:</label>
        <select name="select-todos" id="select-todos" data-native-menu="false">
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>ToDo detail:</div>
      <hr>
      <div id="todo-id">Id: <span></span></div>
      <div id="todo-title">Title: <span></span></div>
      <div id="todo-status">Status: <span></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Additional note: if you need an empty initial selection, you may add an empty `option` to your `select`s, for example with `id=-1` and break the cascading request chain for that non-existent `id`s.

Moreover, depending how big your *model* list is, you can further expand the above template with an additional caching mechanism to avoid double database fetch for already loaded data.

Hope this helps!